# Why kill -9 -1 doesn't work?

Tags: kill

From `man kill`:

> kill -9 -1
>
> Kill all processes you can kill.

But when I do `sudo /bin/kill -9 -1` nothing happens.

My `uname -a` for info:

```
Linux michal-Q530 3.16.0-45-generic #60~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And I'm on Lubuntu.

**UPDATE:**

```
$ ps -e | wc -l
169
$ sudo /bin/kill -9 -1
$ ps -e | wc -l
169
```

Comment: My man page says `kill -s signal ...`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @ott-- still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved by using this:

```
sudo /bin/kill -9 -- -1
```

If the first PID is negative, it has to be preceded by `--` so it's not interpreted as an option.

So the real behavior of `/bin/kill` is distinct from the behavior described in the man page.

Comment: Ok, I missed that in the man page: `kill [-s signal|-p] [--] pid...`

Comment: Does `sudo kill -9 -1` work?

Comment: @cuonglm it doesn't work for me. I have tried it on both `bash` and `dash`.

Comment: @Mike: `sudo /bin/kill -9 -1` work for me on Fedora and CoreOS.

Comment: It seems to be a bug, what is your `util-linux` version?

Comment: 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4