# can't kill a process running on server

Tags: kill

I ran a R console on our server, and the process took much longer time than I expected. Thus I was trying close it by ctrl+z, it didn't work. Finally I just closed the terminal. But the process is still there when I check with top commands. I used kill, but won't kill the process. 
The top command output:

```
 PID   USER     PR   NI  VIRT    RES    SHR  S  %CPU %MEM  TIME+ COMMAND     
27448 zhenyang  20   0 20.133g 0.020t 3.840g R 100.0 21.3  72:00.06 R
```

I checked the website and someone says it might be ctrl+z put the process in background, but fg command won't work.

Anyone help?

Comment: To kill it: `kill 27448`.  To kill it with fire (i.e. this has unwanted side effects, so try it only if the first version doesn't work): `kill -9 27448`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, I have tried both, and both won't work. something weird is that "20.133g   0.020t   3.840g", although I don't quite understand the meaning, they are different from other processes.

Comment: Is it a process from your user? If you don't care killing every single one of your processes, do the big `kill -9 -1`

Comment: There's obviously a defunc process at play here.

Comment: @J.Chomel, I tried  and it works, and I checked before I use the big kill. Thanks!

Comment: @JuliePelletier,  I was afraid using kill -9 -l that I might do something wrong. But It works. As I am not the administrator of the server, and there currently is no process running from my own, except the one I mentioned, so I give it a try. It works. I should be more carefully in future about this!

Comment: BTW, killing process `-1` is a very bad idea.  If the system lets it pass, it will crash the machine, probably rebooting it.  Your sysadmin may not be very happy since it won't do a clean shut down if it works.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Passing -1 as the process ID kills all the processes of the calling user (of any user if the calling user is root) except init. This is standard behavior. A non-root user cannot crash the machine.

Comment: @J.Chomel Given that the intent is to kill a specific process, there is absolutely no reason to kill all processes with -1.

Comment: @Gilles:  I've tried, as a regular user, kill(-1) on old versions of SunOS and Digital and in those two systems it crashed the system.

Comment: @JuliePelletier, you mean you launched `kill -9 -1` with `root` user? Yes of course, it kills every single process owned by the user... [But sometimes it doesn't work](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220175/why-kill-9-1-doesnt-work)... I'm not very accurate on the topic, so I avoided posting it as an answer. It seems to have work for the OP though.

Comment: @J.Chomel:  As I said, it was done with a non-priviledged user.  Note that it didn't work on the command line, just in a C program.  It was most likely a bug in the C library but we didn't dig into it - just did the test as we'd heard of the possible issue.

Answer (score 3):

Run the command `kill` and pass it the process ID, i.e. in your case

```
kill 27448
```

By default, this kills the process, but if the program has set up a signal handler, it may continue to run. If the process keeps running, use

```
kill -KILL 27448
```

(or equivalently `kill -9 27448`). The KILL signal cannot be caught, it always kills the process. ([Maybe not immediately](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/what-if-kill-9-does-not-work) if the process is doing some long input/output, but it does kill it.)

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL`+`Z` does not kill processes, it suspends their execution (aka it stops them). It does this by sending the `TSTP` signal to the process which can be resumed by sending the `CONT` signal to the process.

```
kill -CONT <pid>
```

Once suspended the processes won't respond to other nice signals like `TERM` (which is what `kill` sends by default) until the process is resumed with the `CONT` signal - at which point it will process all pending signals immediately. The exception to this is the `KILL` signal which immediately kills the process without giving it a chance to end gracefully.

```
kill -KILL <pid>
```

This is *generally discouraged* as it will skip any teardown/cleanup the process normally does. Instead of `CTRL+Z` you should use `CTRL+C` to ask the foreground process to end. This sends the `INT` signal to the process which generally (not always) has similar behaviour to the `TERM` signal - it asks the process to end gracefully.

You can read more about linux/bash process job control [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-s-job-control-to-manage-foreground-and-background-processes).